# Timer get interval time

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I created a Timer

```
private static AutoResetEvent autoEvent;
private static Timer stateTimer;
public static void Start()
{
    autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    TimerCallback timerDelegate = new TimerCallback(SomeClass.TimerLoad);
    stateTimer = new Timer(timerDelegate, autoEvent, 1000, 3 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
}
```

from other procedure I change timer:

```
stateTimer.Change(0, 5 * 60 * 1000);
```

now, I need to know what is the interval, is there any appropiate instruction for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use System.Timers.Timer instead, that has an interval property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I have not found a way to do this yet. When faced with the same problem, I resorted to storing the interval whenever I changed my timer.

The "good" way might be to inherit the Timer class and add the property there...

Comment: +1 : Subclassing seems a good idea, nicer than storing a local variable which was my inital thought.

Comment: Ugh =) Well, one could at least make a wrapper to hide the ugly bookkeeping code.

Answer (score 1):

What about the Interval property of Timer ?

Comment: this is not Windows.Form Timer
is a System.Threading.Timer
it does not have Interval property

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you setting the interval in your Change method call, when you specify 5 * 60 * 1000.  So, your interval is 300000.